# Swift Observe dynamic dictionary

Tags: swift, swiftui, observedobject

I'm trying to listen to changes of an element in a dictionary using `@Published`.

I have a dictionary, containing a list of player scores, indexed by player id.
It looks like this:

```swift
class PlayersScore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var scores: [String: PlayerScore] = [:];
}
```

This dictionary is exposed through the property `scores` of a shared instance of a class called `Api`.

```swift
class Api: NSObject {
   static var shared = Api()
   @Published public var scores = PlayersScore()

   func updatePlayerScore(playerId: String, score: PlayerScore) {
       this.scores.scores[playerId] = score
   }
}
```

Sometimes, the score of a player is updated.

I have a view dedicated to a Player that looks like this:

```swift
struct PlayerView: View {
   var player: Player
   @ObservedObject private var scores = Api.shared.scores

   var body: some View {
       HStack {
           Text(player.name)
           Text("Latest score: \(scores.scores[player.id] ?? "not found")")
       }
   }
}
```

When the score of a player is updated, my view re-render.
My problem is that ... when a player score is updated, ALL players views are re-rendered as they all react to changes of the main dictionary.

So, I would like to subscribe to changes on a specific player score in his corresponding view, so only the appropriate view re-renders when necessary.

The player score may not be yet initialised when subscribing or accessing (ie `scores.scores[player.id]` may not exists yet).

Any idea how I could achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Make `PlayerScore` is-a `ObservableObject` and create view for it which will present and observe specific instance of `PlayerScore`

Comment: Thank for your reply @Asperi How could I achieve this? I would need to `@ObserveObject` based on the view parameter `player.id` but I don't know how. Can I do that in the init function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible approach - make `PlayerScore` as a observable class, so PlayersScore will be updated only when new player added, and due to observed specific `PlayerScore` explicitly only corresponding view will be updated on `value` changes.

```
class PlayerScore: ObservableObject {
  var id: String  // say back ref to user

  @Published var value: Int
  // ... other published properties
}

struct PlayerView: View {
   var player: Player
   @ObservedObject private var scores = Api.shared.scores

   var body: some View {
       HStack {
           Text(player.name)
           if let score = scores.scores[player.id] {
              PlayerScoreView(playerScore: score)
           } else {
              Text("No scores")
           }
       }
   }
}

struct PlayerScoreView: View {
  @ObservedObject var playerScore: PlayerScore

  var body: some View {
     Text("Latest score: \(playerScore.value)")
  }
}
```

*Note: this is just a sketch coded here, so might be typo*

Comment: Ok, you helped me to better understand the observable object. Initialy, PlayerScore was a struct, I turned it into a observable object class as you suggest and now I only get the updates on the specific view. Thank you so much.